# Excel multiple rows values addition

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to add the formula that will sum first two rows and excel, put the result in the next column, then move down, take the next two values and put the result below the sum of the previuos one. (it is clear in the picture).
Please any advice would be helpful because my formula is taking the second value and add it on the next one which is not what i need.                                     https://postimg.org/image/st4uie90j/ example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula will work to do what you ask if the columns are adjacent and set the $A$1 to the first cell (top-left of your data set):

=SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT("R" & (ROW($A$1) +(( ROW()-1)*2)) & "C" & (COLUMN()-1),FALSE),0,0,2,1))